# Escaping dilemma in Javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, escaping

I have the following

```
var id='123';

newDiv.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\" TestFunction('"+id+"', false);\"></a>";
```

Which renders `<a href="#" onclick="return Testfunction('123',false);"></a>` in my HTML.

The problem I have is that I wish to take the call to the method TestFunction, and use as a string parameter in my function StepTwo(string, boolean), which would ideally end up in live HTML as shown...

```
<a href="#" onclick="StepTwo("TestFunction('123',false)",true)"></a>
```

notice how the TestFunction is a string here (it is executed within StepTwo using eval).

I have tried to format my JS as by :

```
newDiv.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"StepTwo(\"TestFunction('"+id+"', false);\",true)\"></a>";
```

but while this appears to me correct in my IDE, in the rendered HTML, it as garbelled beyond belief.

Would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using &quot; instead of \"

newDiv.innerHTML = "<a href=&quot;#&quot;...

Answer (score 5):

One of the biggest capital failures on the internet is creating html in javascript by gluing strings together.

```
var mya = document.createElement("a");
mya.href="#"; 
mya.onclick = function(){ 
    StepTwo(function(){ 
        TestFunction('123', false ); 
    }, true );   
};
newDiv.innerHTML = ""; 
newDiv.appendChild(mya);
```

This Eliminates the need for any fancy escaping stuff.

( I probably should do 'onclick' differently, but this should work, I'm trying hard not to just use jQuery code to do everything )

Heres how I would do it in jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){ 

  var container = $("#container"); 
  var link = document.createElement("a"); /* faster than  $("<a></a>"); */
  $(link).attr("href", "Something ( or # )" ); 
  $(link).click( function(){ 
       var doStepTwo = function()
       { 
            TestFunction('123', true ); 
       };
       StepTwo( doStepTwo, false );  /* StepTwo -> doStepTwo -> TestFunction() */
  });
  container.append(link); 
});
```

#### There is no good excuse for gluing strings together in Javascript

All it does is **ADD** overhead of html parsing back into dom structures, and **ADD** potential for XSS based broken HTML. Even *beloved google* get this wrong in some of their advertising scripts and have caused *epic failures* in many cases I have seen ( and they don't want to know about it )

**I don't understand Javascript** is the only excuse, and it's **NOT** a good one.

Comment: FYI - String concatenation is a heck of a lot faster. Useful for say a grid with 1000 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `&quot;` not `"` or `\"` inside an HTML string quoted with double-quotes.

`NewDiv.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"StepTwo(&quot;TestFunction('"+id+"', false);&quot;,true)\"></a>";`

There's probably a better way to do this - any time you find yourself using `eval()` you should stand back and look for a different solution.

Comment: again, right at the same time the other answer. wish i could mark both as being the chosen correct answer. Will throw some votes up your way once I have 15+ reputation. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

You claim that eval is the right thing to do here. I'm not so sure.

Have you considered this approach:

```
<a href="#" onclick="StepTwo(TestFunction,['123',false],true)"></a>
```

and in your StepTwo function

```
function StepTwo(func,args,flag){
    //do what ever you do with the flag
    //instead of eval use the function.apply to call the function.
    func.apply(args);
}
```

Comment: again, thanks. elegant. But eval is correct here in the context of our app. (lol, wish i put a disclaimer in my original post about eval!).

Thanks very much anyway. :-).

If StepTwo were doing ANYTHING different than what it's currently doing, I would avoid eval.

Comment: My answer is not only for you. It's also for all of those who search answers to similar issues. For those eval is likely not the right solution. However you got me curious. What is the key reason why eval is right here?

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry but I'm not allowed to say. I'd be pasting code from work which technically belongs to the company I'm writing it for. I'm sure not much of a fuss would be kicked up but I'd rather keep on the safe side. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the a element and attach to the click event using DOM Methods.

A Javascript Framework (like the ubiquitous jQuery) would make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to alternate your " and '.
2. Maybe you don't need quotes around the 123, because of Javascripts flexible typing.  Pass it without quotes but treat it as a string within TestFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is using eval, it leads to so many potential problems that it's nearly always better to find an alternative solution.

Your immediate problem is that what you really have is

```
<a href="#" onclick="StepTwo("></a>
```

as the next `"` after the start of the onclick attribute, closes it. Use &quot; as others have suggested. And don't use eval.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create the element with `document.createElement`, but if you're not willing to, I guess you could do `<a href="#" onclick="StepTwo('TestFunction(\'123\',false)',true)"></a>` or use `&quot;`.

In your code:

```
newDiv.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"StepTwo('TestFunction(\'"+id+"\', false);\',true)\"></a>";
```

If it doesn't work, try changing "`\'`" to "`\\'`".

Remember that the " character is used to open and close the attribute on HTML tags. If you use it in the attribute's value, the browser will understand it as the close char.

Example:
`<input type="text" value="foo"bar">` will end up being `<input type="text" value="foo">`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys, thanks for all the answers. I find that the quot; seems to work best.

I'll give you guys some votes up once I get more reputation!

In regards to eval(), what you see in the question is a very small snapshot of the application being developed. I understand the woes of eval, however, this is one of those one in a million situations where it's the correct choice for the situation at hand.

It would be understood better if you could see what these functions do (have given them very generic names for stackoverflow).

Thanks again!

Comment: Chances are if you think you have found a legitamate excuse for eval, then you just don't know enough about javascript/dom.

Comment: ( Effective use of closures trumps Eval 99/100 times )

Comment: Understood, and this is that 1/100 times. Cheers. Wish I could talk about it more but it's not my place to talk about the specific code I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="StepTwo('TestFunction(\'123\', false)', true)">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is hella' old now, but if anyone has issues with escaped strings when using eval (and you absolutely have to use eval), I've got a way to avoid problems.

```
var html = '<a href="#\" onclick=" TestFunction(\''+id+'\', false);"></a>';
eval('(function(div, html){div.innerHTML = html;})')(newDiv, html);
```

So, what's going on here?

1. `eval` creates a function that contains two parameters, `div` and `html` and returns it.
2. The function is immediately run with the parameters to the right of the eval function. This is basically like an IIFE.

In this case

```
var myNewMethod = eval('(function(div, html){div.innerHTML = html;})');
```

is basically the same as:

```
var myNewMethod = function(div, html){div.innerHTML = html;}
```

and then we're just doing this:

```
myNewMethod(newDiv, html); //where html had the string containing markup
```

I would suggest not using eval. If it can't be avoided, or if you control all the inputs and there's no risk of injection then this will help in cases where string escapes are an issue.

I also tend to use `Function`, but it isn't any more secure.
Here's the snippet I use:

```
    var feval = function(code) {
    return (new Function(code))();
}
```